# What fiddler do? Why can it fix my application through open and close?

Tags: c#, http, ssl, fiddler

It is not a specific problem because I have more than one experience that fiddler save my app.

A recent example:

I had an excel addin app write in C#. In the app I had a httpclient to connect to my server through ssl. And I ignored the certification in my code explicitly.

The app always worked well(I mean the connection part), but one day in a QA environment, it failed in no causes. The connection seemed to be blocked for long long time.

Coincidentally, we opened the Fiddler and tried to grab some http. Then everything worked fine.

> (Fiddler may do something in the middle)

Then after closing Fiddler, we cannot recreate the problem because all things went back to fine again.

> (Fiddler change something permanently!)

Here are some clues:

1. We use the normal C# http clients System.Net.Http .
2. Our server is ssl (https, but we must ignore the cert)
3. The app was good in the same environment at frist.
4. The lastest change is about the localization, and the test enviroment changed the windows local and language.
5. We are under a company network, using a proxy in the example above.
6. The failure is not the whole connection module, but a specific request.(In our case, a request that post two small xml files including excel itself)

Please give us some hint and guess, so we can feel better on this mystical problem.

Comment: Fiddler changes proxy settings. When you opened fiddler it changed system proxy to itself. After closing fiddler, the proxy settings were reset to default.

Comment: I disagree. After trying the fiddler does set the proxy, but the proxy is not reset to default, it is reset to the last time conf. So it changes nothing before and after in this part.

Comment: You're right. It sets proxy to last config. I guess something happened with system, so reboot or changing proxy setting (to some other config and back) could have the same effect as turning fiddler on and off. It seems to be OS problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How long is a "long long time" exactly?

Fiddler does not make any persistent changes to the system; if you start and stop it, the system is returned to the prior configuration. I suppose it's *remotely* possible that if some configuration setting were corrupt before Fiddler ran, that corruption wouldn't be replicated after Fiddler attempted to reapply it, but we don't know of any such "corrections."

[This article](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/help!-running-fiddler-fixes-my-app-) describes some of the things folks find unexpected in terms of Fiddler "magically" fixing things while it runs.

Comment: Actually, long long means forever.  Good resources, thanks.